# Regex capture words between specific keywords dynamically

Tags: javascript, regex, reactjs

I am building myself a syntax highlighter for React tutorials. Currently I am trying to capture the variable assignment and de-structured properties when importing.

I am able to capture a single variable assignment like so...

code: `import React from 'react';`

regex: `/(?<=\b(import|export|default)\s)(\w+)/gm`

captures: `React`

However, when trying to capture that inline with de-structured properties it fails and I am running into unforseen issues.

**Example**

code: `import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';`

captures: `React`

I Need to capture `React`, `useState`, and `useEffect` but **not** `,`, `{`, or `}`.

Regex is not my forte and I am unsure how to ask this question to get a proper answer. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Reminds me of https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/5260024

Comment: In this specific capture, I'm not parsing html, I am simply trying to capture import declarations. Specifically I need to capture everything between the words 'import' and 'from' that are a-z characters and exclude commas, curly brackets and the actual words 'import' and 'from'

Comment: Well then `(?<=\b(import|export|default)(\w|\s|\,|\{|\}|\*)*)(\w+)(?=.*from)`

Comment: Thank you so much, that works like a charm! Can you please post your comment so I can mark it as the accepted answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  (?<=\b(import|export|default)(\w|\s|\,|\{|\}|\*)*)(\w+)(?=.*from)
```

Line by line:

```
 (?<=\b /*positive lookbehind*/
   (import|export|default) /* for the statements */
   (\w|\s|\,|\{|\}|\*)* /* and for all kinds of chars inbetween */
 )(\w+) /* the word */
 (?=.*from) /* positive lookahead for "from" */
```